# RxView.clicks crashes app

Tags: android, rx-java2, rx-binding

Trying to do some basic RxJava stuff to lear how it works and was trying to show a progress on button click in a login form (with the RxBindings lib) and then make it disappear after a second. But after the progress is shown and I want to hide it the app crashes. Here's the code I trying to do this with,

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    mLoginFormView = findViewById(R.id.login_form);
    mProgressView = findViewById(R.id.login_progress);

    RxView.clicks(findViewById(R.id.email_sign_in_button))
            .doOnNext(new Consumer<Object>() {
                @Override
                public void accept(@NonNull Object o) throws Exception {
                    showProgress(true);
                }
            })
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .delay(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .subscribe(new Consumer<Object>() {
                @Override
                public void accept(@NonNull Object o) throws Exception {
                    showProgress(false);
                }
            }, new Consumer<Throwable>() {
                @Override
                public void accept(@NonNull Throwable throwable) throws Exception {
                    Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Threw: " + throwable, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });
}

private void showProgress(final boolean show) {
    int shortAnimTime = getResources().getInteger(android.R.integer.config_shortAnimTime);

    mLoginFormView.setVisibility(show ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE);
    mLoginFormView.animate().setDuration(shortAnimTime).alpha(
            show ? 0 : 1).setListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
            mLoginFormView.setVisibility(show ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE);
        }
    });

    mProgressView.setVisibility(show ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
    mProgressView.animate().setDuration(shortAnimTime).alpha(
            show ? 1 : 0).setListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
            mProgressView.setVisibility(show ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
        }
    });
}
```

and the crash I get is,

> ComposedException 1 :
>                                                                                 android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the
>   original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
>                                                                                 at android.view.ViewRootImpl.checkThread(ViewRootImpl.java:6357)
>                                                                                 at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl.invalidateChildInParent(ViewRootImpl.java:909)
>                                                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.invalidateChild(ViewGroup.java:4690)
>                                                                                 at android.view.View.invalidateInternal(View.java:11801)
>                                                                                 at android.view.View.invalidate(View.java:11765)
>                                                                                 at android.view.View.setFlags(View.java:9704)
>                                                                                 at android.view.View.setVisibility(View.java:6693)
>                                                                                 at android.widget.FrameLayout.setVisibility(FrameLayout.java:208)
>                                                                                 at
>   com.sample.android.rxlogin.ui.LoginActivity.showProgress(LoginActivity.java:60)
>                                                                                 at
>   com.sample.android.rxlogin.ui.LoginActivity.access$000(LoginActivity.java:19)
>                                                                                 at
>   com.sample.android.rxlogin.ui.LoginActivity$1.accept(LoginActivity.java:44)
>                                                                                 at
>   io.reactivex.internal.observers.LambdaObserver.onNext(LambdaObserver.java:59)
>                                                                                 at
>   io.reactivex.observers.SerializedObserver.onNext(SerializedObserver.java:111)
>                                                                                 at
>   io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableDelay$DelayObserver$1.run(ObservableDelay.java:84)
>                                                                                 at
>   io.reactivex.internal.schedulers.ScheduledRunnable.run(ScheduledRunnable.java:59)
>                                                                                 at
>   io.reactivex.internal.schedulers.ScheduledRunnable.call(ScheduledRunnable.java:51)
>                                                                                 at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
>                                                                                 at
>   java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:152)
>                                                                                 at
>   java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:265)
>                                                                                 at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
>                                                                                 at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
>                                                                                 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
>                                                                              Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside
>   thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
>                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.(Handler.java:200)
>                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.(Handler.java:114)
>                                                                                 at android.widget.Toast$TN.(Toast.java:344)
>                                                                                 at android.widget.Toast.(Toast.java:100)
>                                                                                 at android.widget.Toast.makeText(Toast.java:258)
>                                                                                 at
>   com.sample.android.rxlogin.ui.LoginActivity$2.accept(LoginActivity.java:49)
>                                                                                 at
>   com.sample.android.rxlogin.ui.LoginActivity$2.accept(LoginActivity.java:46)
>                                                                                 at
>   io.reactivex.internal.observers.LambdaObserver.onError(LambdaObserver.java:72)
>                                                                                 at
>   io.reactivex.internal.observers.LambdaObserver.onNext(LambdaObserver.java:62)
>                                                                                 at
>   io.reactivex.observers.SerializedObserver.onNext(SerializedObserver.java:111)
>                                                                                 at
>   io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableDelay$DelayObserver$1.run(ObservableDelay.java:84)
>                                                                                 at
>   io.reactivex.internal.schedulers.ScheduledRunnable.run(ScheduledRunnable.java:59)
>                                                                                     at io.reactivex.internal.schedulers.Schedul

I can't understand why this should crash though, since I am using `observeOn()` with the main Android thread. Could someone please explain what's wrong here? and whats the right way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Just move your `.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())` right after the `.delay(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)` block.

Some operators by default don't operate on any particular scheduler, but `delay` does, as you can se in the [documentation](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/io/reactivex/Observable.html#delay(long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit)) it operates in the `computation()` scheduler (at least the version of the delay that you are using).

Answer (score -2):

You need to use `subscribeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())`.

The [`onClickListener`](https://github.com/JakeWharton/RxBinding/blob/master/rxbinding/src/main/java/com/jakewharton/rxbinding2/view/ViewClickObservable.java#L25) that Rx uses is set on the `View` during the subscription.

Comment: how does that change things? (btw still crashes)

Comment: Wouldn't sorry, didn't read your stacktrace. The subscription will happen on the main thread anyway as that's where you are when you start. You need to move your `observeOn` to before the `doOnNext`

Comment: Oh, delay causes the stream to jump to `Schedulers.computation()` by default.  Move the `observeOn` to just before the `subscribe`.

Comment: is there a explanation of what the issue is and why it needs to be moved to the just before the subscribe? (a good article for a beginner would also be appreciated)

Comment: The explanation is that the delay is causing the the thread to change. And only the main thread can touch UI elements, so after the delay you need to tell it come back to the main thread.

Comment: so does delay always create another thread? instead of sleeping on the same thread? is there another operator that can sleep on the same thread?
 Also why didn't the `observeOn()` at the start work? Does  using`observeOn()` mean that all calls after it will use the thread that's used in `observeOn()`?

Comment: Delay always uses the same thread, a predefined one called 'computation'. There's an overload the use any scheduler you like, but doing the delay on the UI thread will hang your app for the duration of the delay. Also, the order of operations matters, you can't come back to the main thread until after you've left.

Comment: thanks could you please add the explanation into the answer